# How do Tomcat Session, and Oracle Database connection interact with each other in a Java Spring web application?

Tags: spring, oracle, tomcat

I am currently working on a Spring MVC web application that is hosted on a tomcat server and is connected to an Oracle database.

I would like to know in what cicumstances does the Tomcat user session or the oracle DB connection get refresed. For example, does refreshing the webpage refresh both sessions? Does doing an ajax call refresh one or both sessions? Will doing an static action on a webpage refresh the tomcat session, and not the oracle one? In general where can one session be refeshed, but not the other?

I know this can potentally vary between configurations, but I would like a general guideline on how these interactions works.

Comment: Hi you would need to show how is your application configured. Is it using database connections managed by Tomcat? If so (even if it is spring) it would be managed by a connection pool which would decide when to "refresh" the connection (not actually a refresh, but a lookup on available connections)... The tomcat session though (again depending on configuration and app setup) would refresh on each call...

Comment: It's using the oracle jdbc connector configured in the pom.xml.Aside from that everything is set to default.

Comment: This configuration you mentioned is a dependency, not a configuration. You need to look how your project is configured. If it spring look either for xml / properties files in the resources folder or classes annotated with `@Configuration`